# I would like separate Object values based on Object keys

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Need to merge other country cities data into single object. my inputs are below

```
result = {
  "Bangalore": [
    {
      "Type": "Sale",
      "Date": "2021-07-10",
    },

    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-07-03",
    }
  ],
  "Delhi": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ],
  "Chennai": [
    {
      "Type": "Production",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    },
    {
      "Type": "Production",
      "Date": "2021-07-11",
    },
  ],
  "Goa": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ],
    "sydney": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ],
    "melbourne": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ]

}
```

I have other country cities array is below

```
let arr = [
    "sydney",
    "melbourne"
  ]
```

I tried with below snippet its not working.

```
  let {sydney,melbourne,...final}=result;

let othercity = [...sydney,...melbourne]

console.log(final)
```

Actually When I pass variable into `let {sydney,melbourne,...final}` its working as expected. But I want to pass this variable `sydney,melbourne` dynamically. ie 'let {...arr,...final}=result;'

Expected output results:
IndiaCities

```
{
  "Bangalore": [
    {
      "Type": "Sale",
      "Date": "2021-07-10"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-07-03"
    }
  ],
  "Delhi": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30"
    }
  ],
  "Chennai": [
    {
      "Type": "Production",
      "Date": "2021-06-30"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Production",
      "Date": "2021-07-11"
    }
  ],
  "Goa": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30"
    }
  ]
}
```

otherCitys

```
{"othercities":[
  {
     "Type": "Product",
     "Date": "2021-06-30"
   },
   {
     "Type": "Product",
     "Date": "2021-06-30"
   }
]}
```

How to resolve this destructing concept. your answer is greatly appreciated

```js
let result = {
  "Bangalore": [
    {
      "Type": "Sale",
      "Date": "2021-07-10",
    },

    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-07-03",
    }
  ],
  "Delhi": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ],
  "Chennai": [
    {
      "Type": "Production",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    },
    {
      "Type": "Production",
      "Date": "2021-07-11",
    },
  ],
  "Goa": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ],
    "sydney": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ],
    "melbourne": [
    {
      "Type": "Product",
      "Date": "2021-06-30",
    }
  ]

}

let arr = [
    "sydney",
    "melbourne"
  ]
  
  let {sydney,melbourne,...final}=result;

let othercity = [...sydney,...melbourne]

  console.log(othercity)

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Please provide all your data, and what you expect as result. Also, not needed to write full objects, create a simple example to reproduce your issue.

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: redeclaration of let arr",` .. first, your code needs to run, second, what do you expect `final` to be?

Comment: Don't use destructing if you don't know how exactly destructuring works. It's only syntactic sugar. Write the long form to be explicit.

Comment: @Bergi  I updated my question and expected outcome

Comment: @Jaromanda final variable hold `chennai,bangalore,goa,delhi` city data.

Comment: @Jay still not clear. Just add what is your expecterd result as a code.

Comment: please show exactly, with correct syntax :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I added expected results. Indian cities data should be one object. other country cities data should be in another object. I hope you understand

Comment: @decpk I updated my expectation

Comment: @Jay Answered. Please check. Is that what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct when you are using

```
const { sydney, melbourne, ...indianCities } = result;
```

since you want to accumulate the result into an object that contain a property `otherCities` which is an array of two object i.e. `sydney` and `melbourne`

```
const othercitiesObj = {
  otherCities: [...sydney, ...melbourne],
};
```

```js
const result = {
  Bangalore: [
    {
      Type: "Sale",
      Date: "2021-07-10",
    },

    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-07-03",
    },
  ],
  Delhi: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  Chennai: [
    {
      Type: "Production",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
    {
      Type: "Production",
      Date: "2021-07-11",
    },
  ],
  Goa: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  sydney: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  melbourne: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
};

let arr = ["sydney", "melbourne"];

const { sydney, melbourne, ...indianCities } = result;
const othercitiesObj = {
  otherCities: [...sydney, ...melbourne],
};

console.log(othercitiesObj);
```

**Edited: Since you want dynamic city**

```js
const result = {
  Bangalore: [
    {
      Type: "Sale",
      Date: "2021-07-10",
    },

    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-07-03",
    },
  ],
  Delhi: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  Chennai: [
    {
      Type: "Production",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
    {
      Type: "Production",
      Date: "2021-07-11",
    },
  ],
  Goa: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  sydney: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  melbourne: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
};

let arr = ["sydney", "melbourne"];

const { sydney, melbourne, ...indianCities } = result;
const othercitiesObj = {
  otherCities: arr.flatMap((city) => result[city]),
};

console.log(othercitiesObj);
```

But if there is a city that doesn't exist in the `arr` array then you can use reduce

```js
const result = {
  Bangalore: [
    {
      Type: "Sale",
      Date: "2021-07-10",
    },

    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-07-03",
    },
  ],
  Delhi: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  Chennai: [
    {
      Type: "Production",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
    {
      Type: "Production",
      Date: "2021-07-11",
    },
  ],
  Goa: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  sydney: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
  melbourne: [
    {
      Type: "Product",
      Date: "2021-06-30",
    },
  ],
};

let arr = ["sydney", "melbourne", "bhuna"];

const { sydney, melbourne, ...indianCities } = result;
const othercitiesObj = {
  otherCities: arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (result[curr]) acc = [...acc, ...result[curr]];
    return acc;
  }, []),
};

console.log(othercitiesObj);
```

Comment: This result I got it already but 'arr' ie array I have to pass dynamically and get the othercities data

Comment: @deckpk I fixed myself this what I expected `
  let arrRef: any = [];
  arr.map(item => {
    if (result[item]) {
      arrRef.push(...result[item]);
      delete result[item];
    }
  });
  return arrRef;
`

Comment: Thanks for you help